# Can Silverlight store data retrieved from a WCF service locally?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, variables

Is it possible to save some result from wcf service in variable (inside my silverlight app)? For example : (why myvariable is null) ? thx for help

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{

    private int myvariable;
    ....

    public void s_DoWorkCompleted(object o, ServiceReference1.DoWorkCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        myvariable = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. "myvariable" is an int, and couldn't be null. Even if it's never assigned it would have a value of zero.

Comment: Considering @Mike Hildner's comment, are you sure your question is a true reflection of your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is totally possible and quite routine.  Just remember that what you get back from the server is a copy and not the original variable itself.  You can't pull and object back, modify it on the client, and expect the server to get the update.  You have to send the object back to the server to do that.

If you are storing null into myvariable, you need to set a breakpoint in your s_DoWorkCompleted to make sure 1) it is getting reached and 2) e.Result isn't null itself.  If e.Result is null, you need to go back to your service to ensure it is working.

Comment: when s_DoWorkCompleted  is completed myvariable gets null,
( 1) yes its gettin reached  2) e.Result isnt null) When I set breakpoint inside s_DoWorkCompleted myvariable gets some value, but after it when finished myvariabe gets null .

Comment: @user - what you are saying makes no sense. Are you sure you don't have multiple calls returning through the same handler? or another thread manipulating `myvariable`? Do you have more code you should be showing us to get an accurate answer?

Comment: ok ,sorry the problem was in my WCF service . Btw Thanks for your answers